# Join two mysql tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have two mysql tables that have the following structure:

**Table 1:**

```
---ID---------NAME-------
---1----- page name 1 ---
---2----- page name 2 ---
---3----- page name 3 ---
```

**Table 2:**

```
----ID---PAGE ID---------NAME------
-----1-----1-------- page name 1 ---
-----2-----2-------- page name 2 ---
-----3-----3-------- page name 3 ---
-----4-----1-------- page name 1 ---
-----5-----2-------- page name 2 ---
-----6-----3-------- page name 3 ---
-----7-----1-------- page name 1 ---
-----8-----2-------- page name 2 ---
-----9-----3-------- page name 3 ---
```

As you can see in **table 2** each page is mentioned several times.

I want to join **Table 1** on **Table 2** only with the newest records in **Table 2**, in this case the newest three records only! ("newest" means records with higher IDs) Is that possible using mysql?

Comment: What defines "newest record"? The ones with the highest IDs? A date/time field you've not listed?

Comment: Define "newest". I cannot see any timestamp in Table2 (that is not really your table name, is it?)

Comment: And also which field in Table2 is the foreign key that relates it to Table1?

Comment: "Newest" means highest IDs...

Comment: What's the difference between Table1.Name and Table2.Name? Is that data just duplicated?

Comment: No difference between the names. The data is duplicated! There are also some other fields in Table 2 which I didn't mention to simplify the example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table2

```
----ID---PAGE ID----
-----1-----1-------- 
-----2-----2-------- 
-----3-----3-------- 
-----4-----1-------- 
-----5-----2-------- 
-----6-----3-------- 
-----7-----1-------- 
-----8-----2-------- 
-----9-----3--------
```

and

```
SELECT Table1.ID, PAGE_ID, NAME
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.PAGE_ID
WHERE ... put your condition for latest if other when highest ID
ORDER BY Table1.ID DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table1.ID, PAGE_ID, NAME 
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID = Table2.PAGE_ID 
WHERE Table2.ID = MAX(Table2.ID) 
GROUP BY Table1.ID 
LIMIT 3
```

should work